# ul + li + font awesome + href

Tags: html, css

хочу сделать список ul чтобы не писать по 100 раз стиль для каждой иконки.

```
ul#menu li {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 30px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;}

<ul id="menu" type="none">
<li><a href="http://vk.com/url"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-steam" href="http://url.ru"></i></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-code" href="http://url.ru"></i></li>
```

все работает, но не выдается цвет для иконки.

Comment: Вы бы хоть сказали, какой цвет у иконок выдаётся вместо нужного

Answer (score 1):

```
  ul#menu li i.fa{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Ну хоть бы `i.fa` для приличия написали что ли

Comment: Они все .fa, зачем давать лишнюю нагрузку?

Comment: Во-первых, а вдруг в будущем будут не все? Во-вторых, лишнюю нагрузку дают как раз селекторы тегов: браузер обрабатывает CSS-селекторы справа налево, и с таким селектором он будет пробегаться по АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕМ `i` на АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕЙ странице, что скажется на производительности далеко не лучшим образом (если страница большая — Яндекс подтвердит). Селекторы классов намного производительнее селекторов тегов

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)

Comment: @user300665 а вас никто и не критикует. Код из ответа возможно вам поможет

Comment: Тогда я прошу прощения, но в данной ситуации уместно написать и так. Когда будут другие элементы, тогда да.
А вообще в таком случае просто лучше использовать sass и не морочить голову себе.

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, буду благодарен, если вы закроете вопрос.